# 動画再生アプリを作りたい！（データベースの質問）

Tags: swift, 動画, database

今回は方法についての質問です。
iOSアプリで、YouTubeやTikTokみたいに動画系のアプリを作りたいなと考えています。

データベースに動画をどのようにして格納したらいいのかわからず質問しました！

いくつか調べても、わからないので教えて欲しいです。

Comment: 「動画系のアプリを作りたい」で、いきなり「データベース」などといわれると何が何やらさっぱりわからないです。例に挙げられた「youtubeやTicktock」(TikTokのこと?)は、Webサービスとしての動画再生機能があってのアプリであり、Webサービスに動画を保存したり、Webサービスから動画を取り出して再生したりするだけのものです。あなたはどこかよその作った動画Webサービス上の動画再生アプリを作りたいのでしょうか、それとも自前で動画Webサービスを作成したいのでしょうか?

Comment: 自前で動画webサービスを作りたいです

Comment: それでは、「動画webサービス」に耐えられるだけのスペックのサーバを準備することを含めて膨大な量の作業が必要になります。ある程度はご自身で調べて質問内容を絞り込んでください。「動画Webサービス事業を始めたい」と言うだけでは、一つの質問とするには解決しなければいけない課題の範囲が広すぎます。

Comment: 画像などと同様にDBに投入することはもちろん可能かと思いますが、そもそも大きなバイナリファイルをDBに保存することはあまりメリットはないかもしれません。単にファイルシステムもしくはPaasのストレージサービスを利用するほうがより良いかもと思いました。

Comment: アプリを作りたいとのことですが、動画はサーバー側のデータベースに格納するのでしょうか？その場合サーバー側のソフト作成も必要になります。

Comment: ストリーミングサーバを検索してみてください。https://qiita.com/yo_dazy/items/e14464367ec8d4a26b6a

Answer (score 1):

データベースがRDBならば、`ラージオブジェクト`や`LOB`に格納するのが一般的だと思います。

※RDBを使うことが前提の場合です、動画データのファイルをファイルシステム上に置いておいて、そのパスをテーブルで管理する方法もよくあります。